# How to get access to webpack-dev-server with external IP

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I've got my simple login website fully coded and functional on the webpack dev server. how can i display it with my external IP? I've already port forwarded my router on port 9000 but when i tried www.myIp:portnumber its not working.
Below is my webpack config for the webpack dev server.

```
//Webpack config
module.exports = {
  entry: './app/main.js',
  output: {
    path: './app',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    contentBase: './app',
    port: 9000
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You can open it up by passing the --host option.
`webpack-dev-server --port 3000 --hot --host 0.0.0.0` https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/147

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the host property:

```
devServer: {
    inline: true,
    contentBase: './app',
    port: 9000,
    host: '0.0.0.0'
  }
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-host-cli-only

Comment: thank you so much, this solved it for me. After this i just needed to disable the new Hostcheck they implmented in the webpack-dev-server and im now able to access it externallly!